# How does fast user switching affect a windows service?

Tags: windows, performance, service, switching

How does fast user switching affect a windows service? Are the services suspended or do they keep running in the background when a different user logs in?

Comment: Hmm, I did vote to close because I assumed this isn't programming related; but perhaps it is (you may like to explain why you are worried, unless this is your only question).

Comment: It is programming related, I am programming a windows service and wasn't sure if it would still run if a different user logs in using fast user switching. 

Thank you Michael for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Vista, services run in session 0.  This session is always running.  User sessions are session 1 on up.  Even as users connect and disconnect from sessions, log on to new sessions, and so on, the services keep running and session 0 is never torn down.  The only effect on services is they (optionally) receive notifications such as session connect, log on, and so on.

On XP, services run in session 0 and so does the initial user who logs on.  This session is never torn down, and may or may not have an interactive user connected to it.  Besides this, the behavior is the same as Vista.

Answer (score 3):

They keep running; they run as their own users (whatever you set).

Answer (score 3):

Windows services run in the background even if no user is logged in. Switching between users should have no impact on a properly written service.